# ajax - Best way to keep a long polling connection open

Tags: javascript, ajax, long-polling

I am developing a simple chat application for learning purposes. I am using long-polling to keep my chat updated. Now this is what I am doing-:

1. Client makes a request to server.
2. If server has update then it sends it. Otherwise step 3.
3. Server lets the request hang until update is available.
4. If request times out server sends back "Keep-Alive" and user makes a new request (step 1).

Is this the best way to do it ? Is there anything more optimized than this ? 
Should I consider HTTP Streaming to HTTP Long Polling since it reduces overhead ?

I am using Java Servlets to do this but this more of an AJAX question, so thats why I didn't add any code. I will if that's required.

Comment: why not do it with short polling? just poll sending last msg id in the request so the server knows where you at and will return new stuff only? long lasting connections seem awkward in this example

Comment: @user3012759 What is the interval at which I should check for new message ? Also using short polling the chat won't be realtime AFAIK. For example if a user posts a msg at n time and the web app checks for messages at m time then the transfer is slightly delayed. 

Would HTTP Streaming be a better alternative ?

Comment: interval can be whatever you fancy, it's an easy change and you can tweak it till it feels right. as for real-time, nothing is real time, but in general you post a msg to the server and update your msg display from server so there won't be inconsistencies as such, just delay based on your polling interval

Comment: @user3012759 Would HTTP streaming be a better alternative ? I hear the latency is lower than polling and the compatibility is greater than WebSockets

Comment: it seems you're hell bent on streaming... go for it then, imho it's surly less compatible than web sockets that everyone uses and supports... since it's for learning purpose go ahead and try streaming see how far you get and how easy it is, and then try the other approach compare and derive conclusions! gl

Answer (score 0):

What you have suggested would certainly work. Another options is WebSockets, though it is relatively new technology and it is not supported in older browsers.

[Web Sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets)

Comment: No I am not going to use websockets because as you pointed out yourself that they are not supported in older browsers.

Comment: @Heidi Ok, well you asked for other options and I provided one.

Comment: What about HTTP Streaming ? Can that be used to implement chat ?